# ASPX GridView update with RadioButtonList not working

Tags: asp.net, gridview, radiobuttonlist

I've got an ASPX page with a GridView bound to a SqlDataSource, containing a RadioButtonList in each row:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwSomeGridView" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsSomeDataSource">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SomeHeader">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSomeRBL" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%#(bool)Eval("SomeColumn") ? "1" : "0"%>'>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="ABC" Value="1" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="XYZ" Value="0" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lblSomeLabel" Text='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("SomeFolumn")) ? "SomeString" : "SomeOtherString" />
            </ItemTemplate>
    ....
```

The SqlDataSource has an UpdateCommand in which I have to pass the selected RadioButton, but unfortunately I cannot get this to work:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" ConnectionString="..." ID="sdsSomeDataSource" runat="Server" UpdateCommand="UPDATE someTable SET someColumn = @SomeColumn" OnUpdating="OnSqlUpdating"
```

...

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="SomeColumn" ControlID="gvwSomeGridView$rblSomeRBL" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

Now this approach doesn't work as the RadioButtonList does get a different ID for every row. I also couldn't find any other pages to point me in the right direction, so hopefully someone at stackoverflow might be able to help.

I do have a very ugly working solution with attaching to the OnUpdating event of the SqlDataSource and then looping over all GridView rows to find the row in which the RadioButtonList control is not null (the one row that is being updated), but I do hope that there is a better way to solve this issue.

**Edit**

As requested the ugly code for OnSqlUpdating:

```cs
protected void OnSqlUpdating( object source, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e )
{
    RadioButtonList radioButtonList = null;
    foreach( GridViewRow row in gvwSomeGridView.Rows )
    {
        if( row.FindControl( "rblSomeRBL" ) != null )
        {
            radioButtonList = row.FindControl( "rblSomeRBL" ) as RadioButtonList;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( radioButtonList != null )
    {
        int selectedValue = 0;
        if( Int32.TryParse( radioButtonList.SelectedValue, out selectedValue ) )
        {
            SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = new SqlParameter[ e.Command.Parameters.Count + 1 ];
            e.Command.Parameters.CopyTo( sqlParameter, 0 );
            sqlParameters[ sqlParameters.Length - 1 ] = new SqlParameter( "SomeColumn", SqlDbType.Bit )
            {
                Value = selectedValue
            }

            e.Command.Parameters.Clear();
            e.Command.Parameters.AddRange( sqlParameters );         
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

G.

Comment: Please show your updating event code.

Comment: Updated question with the corresponding code - I hope that there is another way to solve this, as this looks really ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add UpdateParameter in the SslDataSource with the following.

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "rblSomeRBL" Name="SomeColumn" Type="String" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work as the "rblSomeRBL" cannot be found. As shown in my original post you can get it to work for single records if you hard-code the id of the RadioButtonList, e.g. ControlID="gvwSomeGridView$rblSomeRBL", but of course this doesn't work for multiple rows as the id changes.

Answer (score 0):

i just found out that you can use the gridview's RowUpdating event:

```
 <asp:Parameter Name="SomeColumn" Type="String" />

protected void gvwSomeGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

   GridViewRow row = gvwSomeGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];

   RadioButtonList rblSomeRBL= row.Cells[0].Controls[0].FindControl("rblSomeRBL") as RadioButtonList;

   if (rblSomeRBL!= null)
   {
        sdsSomeDataSource.UpdateParameters["SomeColumn"].DefaultValue = rblSomeRBL.SelectedValue;
   }

    gvwSomeGridView.EditIndex = -1;
}
```